# Use the transition-delay option (css) and JS to make a div move

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a function that moves a block smoothly. I prefer to use the CSS option 'transition-duration' for this, but it doesn't seem to work for the position. I checked, and it does work for background-color...

CSS file

```
 #cart {
            position: relative;
            transition-duration: 0.5s;
            background-color: green;
        }
```

JS file

```
function start() {
    document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML = "test2";
    document.getElementById("cart").style.left = "100";
    document.getElementById("cart").style.background = "gray";
}
```

So the background-color does change in 2 seconds instead of instantly while the position just changes the instant you use the function. Is there a way to use the 'transition-duration' for the style.left in JS? Or do I have to use something else to make the div move smoothly?

**Answer:**

The solution is that for transition-duration to do anything, it has to be declared beforehand. This means that because I didn't specify a position in a non-animated state, the movement is done instantly. Another solution is to use `transition: left 0.5s` since this doesn't require any CSS-styling of the sort.

Comment: Try declaring left in the CSS initially. (background-color is declared and that seems to be working)

Comment: As an additional, if the block is a fixed width check out example #3 in this fiddle (uses calc) https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/j2an4sgx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS for "left" isn't declared in the CSS before it's added in the JS. Also "100" is an invalid value for CSS position (note the added "px" in the following example).

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MissionMike/adj4j6tr/

HTML:

```
<div id="cart">TEST</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cart {
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  background-color: green;
  left: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML = "test2";
document.getElementById("cart").style.left = "100px";
document.getElementById("cart").style.background = "gray";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use transition: left 0.5s linear; as you haven't said what property you're transitioning.

Also, put the styles you want to change to in a class and apply the class with js instead.

Also, you probably want to transition an absolute item inside a relative container, not apply 'left' to a relative element.